# uploadify and flash v.12

Tags: flash, uploadify

I installed uploadify on my website. All is working with the latest flash version, but when I check it in flash v. 12.0.0.70, I see this:

[image]

It happens with all files.

Also I installed SwfUpload plugin, it have problems with flash v.12 too.

SWF Upload debug return this:

```
SWF DEBUG: SWFUpload Init Complete
SWF DEBUG: 
SWF DEBUG: ----- SWF DEBUG OUTPUT ----
SWF DEBUG: Build Number:           SWFUPLOAD 2.2.0
SWF DEBUG: movieName:              SWFUpload_0
SWF DEBUG: Upload URL:             /js/swfupload/upload.php
SWF DEBUG: File Types String:      *.doc; *.docx; *.rtf; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png; *.bmp; *.gif; *.pdf; *.DOC; *.DOCX; *.RTF; *.JPG; *.JPEG; *.PNG; *.BMP; *.GIF; *.PDF
SWF DEBUG: Parsed File Types:      doc,docx,rtf,jpg,jpeg,png,bmp,gif,pdf,doc,docx,rtf,jpg,jpeg,png,bmp,gif,pdf
SWF DEBUG: HTTP Success:           0
SWF DEBUG: File Types Description: Images (*.doc; *.docx; *.rtf; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png; *.bmp; *.gif; *.pdf; *.DOC; *.DOCX; *.RTF; *.JPG; *.JPEG; *.PNG; *.BMP; *.GIF; *.PDF)
SWF DEBUG: File Size Limit:        10485760 bytes
SWF DEBUG: File Upload Limit:      0
SWF DEBUG: File Queue Limit:       0
SWF DEBUG: Post Params:
SWF DEBUG: ----- END SWF DEBUG OUTPUT ----
SWF DEBUG: 
SWF DEBUG: Event: fileDialogStart : Browsing files. Multi Select. Allowed file types: *.doc; *.docx; *.rtf; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png; *.bmp; *.gif; *.pdf; *.DOC; *.DOCX; *.RTF; *.JPG; *.JPEG; *.PNG; *.BMP; *.GIF; *.PDF
SWF DEBUG: Select Handler: Received the files selected from the dialog. Processing the file list...
SWF DEBUG: Event: fileQueueError : File is zero bytes or FileReference is invalid.
SWF DEBUG: Event: fileDialogComplete : Finished processing selected files. Files selected: 1. Files Queued: 0
SWF DEBUG: StartUpload: First file in queue
SWF DEBUG: StartUpload(): No files found in the queue.
```